# Why won't my d3 html div tooltips hide on mouseout?

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

So I have my html tooltip defined in **myview.haml**:

```html
<div id="tooltip" class="hidden">
  <span id="value">whatever</span>
</div>
```

Which has the following style

```css
#tooltip { 
  position: absolute; 
  somestyleattributteshere;  
  pointer-events: none; 
}

#tooltip.hidden { 
  display: none;
}
```

My html div tooltips show on mouseover like so (coffeescript):

```js
msBarTextLabels.on("mouseover", (d) ->
                   xPosition = svgContainer.offsetLeft
                   yPosition = svgContainer.offsetTop
                   d3.select("#tooltip")
.select("#value")
.html(('charge:' + d.charge + '<br/>intensity: ' + d.m_intensity)
      d3.select("#tooltip").classed("hidden", false)
)
msBarTextLabels.on("mouseout", d3.select("#tooltip").classed("hidden", true) )
```

So the tooltips un-hide correctly on mouseover with the correct data and all, but they do not hide on mouseout,

Any hint on why is that happening?

Thanks

Comment: I'm no expert on Coffeescript, but it looks like in the second case you haven't actually defined a function to be called, but code that gets called only once. Maybe something like `() -> d3.select...`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Lars said, you're not actually passing a callback function to the `mouseout` handler.  Instead, it's actually executing `d3.select("#tooltip").classed("hidden", true)` and passing the result (a d3 selection).  Change to:

```
msBarTextLabels.on("mouseout", (d) ->
    d3.select("#tooltip").classed("hidden", true)
)
```

Comment: That totally did the trick. Embarrasing how obvious the thing was.